# Long distance wifi internet

Tags: ieee-802.11, internet

Is it possible to supply internet up to 5km-10km using wifi ? If yes how ?

Me and my friend want to get Internet in our Village. Our current options are 1. Mobile internet(not cost effective at all) 2. Local Broadband provider (which is over 5km away so it's practically not suitable to use cable in this long distance moreover it's rural area)

Which is why we need something to broadcast internet up to 5km-10km wirelessly. Googled but not getting anything specific or maybe my knowledge of networking is too poor to understand.

Please HELP!

Comment: Wi-Fi is designed for LANs. What you are proposing is usually done with microwave connections or fiber-optic cable.

Comment: so there is no other way ? how far can i spread internet with Wi-Fi technology ?

Comment: Wi-Fi has been used on point-to-point links for a few kilometers, but You can't just have it blanket the village. Remember that Wi-Fi is a bi-directional protocol, so the radios in the clients must reach back to the AP, too. This is not really how Wi-Fi was designed, and you would be taking a huge gamble that it would work.

Comment: Normal cheap wifi usually does not go beyond 100 m though, after that the signal is to weak.

Comment: [Tegola](http://www.ed.ac.uk/research/impact/science-ineering/community-wireless-broadband-project)

Any Idea about this project ? Is it something completely new or they have somehow enhanced the existing Wi-Fi technology ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have line of sight then it should be possible to set up a wireless link over a few kilometers. You would want high gain antennas on both ends, you could either (ab)use wi-fi gear or look for gear designed for the purpose.

Getting the antennas as high off the ground as possible is nearly always a good idea to ensure you get the line of sight path and to reduce the impact of ground reflections.

Be aware that simply slapping high gain antennas on wifi gear may exceed effective radiated power limitations in radio regulations. If you care about being legal you would need to check your local laws and quite probablly turn down the transmit power. Having the high gain antennas still helps even with reduced transmit power because high gain antennas help both transmission and reception.

If you want to connect devices wirelessly at the endpoint you would use a seperate wifi network with an omnidirectional anntena for that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to connect WiFi devices in your village to the Internet, but the closest reasonable-cost Internet access point is over 5 km away.

One possible approach:

(1) Set up each WiFi access point in your village in "[wireless mesh network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wireless_mesh_network) mode", so each WiFi device talks to the closest access point, which relays packets to the next WiFi access point, and so on.
(This is the first step toward [Municipal Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_Wi-Fi)) and [Wireless community network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_community_network)).

(2) Install some [backhaul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/backhaul_(telecommunications)) point-to-point link from your Internet access point over the 5km to some convenient convenient Point (POP) in or near your village.

In my part of the world, common backhaul options for carrying broadband Internet data include:

- small wire mesh dishes ones on top of roof pointed at the nearest tower of a few "[wireless cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wireless_cable)" internet service providers ("[fixed wireless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/fixed_wireless)").
- big shrouded solid microwave radio-relay dishes on tall towers owned by the telephone company every 30 or 40 miles
- coax cable ([cable Internet access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cable_Internet_access))
- telephone wires ([digital subscriber line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/digital_subscriber_line))
- fiber optic cables

I hear that other backhaul options for carrying broadband Internet data a few kilometers include:

- [broadband over power lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/broadband_over_power_lines)
- free-space optical communication such as [RONJA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RONJA)
- [long-range Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_Wi-Fi) (point-to-point)
- [WiMAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX)

(3) Connect the wireless mesh to the point-to-point link, with a short "Ethernet cable" between your Point and the nearest WiFi access point.

Would any of the approaches used by [South African wireless community networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_wireless_community_networks) or the [Seattle Wireless Community Wireless Network](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208194853/http://www.seattlewireless.net/HardwareComparison) work for you?

With everything else held equal, the more focused (or "directional") a radio antenna is, the longer the distance one can communicate with it.
So antennas designed to communicate in all directions ("omnidirectional", "broadcast") generally communicate over very short distances.
When people want to communicate over long distances with radio, we are forced to use very directional antennas and point-to-point communications, and we spend a lot of time aiming one antenna at the other antenna to get the best signal.